# Adding class to the javascript element with the email validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding the user to the list and validating the email and tried to add error class when the email is invalid but it is not working properly. I am able to find the root cause where I am doing it wrong

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
    <h2>Add a User:</h2>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="name">
    <input id="email" type="text"  name="email" placeholder="email">
    <button onclick='return addUser();' type="submit">add user</button>
</form>

<h2>UsersList:</h2>
<ul id="users"></ul>
```

**JS**

```
function addUser(){
    var list = document.getElementById('users');
    var username =document.getElementById('username').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    if (email.value != '') 
    {
        reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
        if (reg.test(email.value) == true) {
            entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(username + ' ' + email));
            list.appendChild(entry);
            return false;
        }
        else {
            email.className += 'errorclasss';
            return false;                             

        }
```

**CSS**

```
.errorclass{
    border: 1px red solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are defining `email` as `document.getElementById('email').value`, but then you are testing against `email.value`. Change this

```
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
```

to this

```
var email = document.getElementById('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be due to the fact that you've spelt `errorclass` wrong?

In the `else` part of the if statement, you should change the first line to

`email.className += 'errorClass';`

Comment: I am trying to enter xyx.xyy in my email field it is not validating the pattern.. http://jsfiddle.net/RQt5R/22/  and my message is not displaying.

Comment: am I doing wrong in this pattern /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/